# How to synchronize clocks over internet?

Tags: synchronization, clock

How do I synchronize client's clock with server's clock over variable latency network (Internet) with good accuracy (to 50ms)? Is it possible? Do I have to host NTP server to do that? If yes - are there good, commonly available implementations in Java or C#?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the OS. If you're on an Active Directory domain, it's done automatically.

See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307897